# How to get type of the first element in array?

Tags: typescript

I have an array of items with different types:

```js
const x = ['y', 2, true];
```

I'd like to extract the type of the first element (here `string` because `'y'` is a `string`).

I tried 3 things:

- got `(string | number | boolean)`:

  ```js
  type FirstElementType = typeof x[0];
  ```
- got `never`:

  ```js
  type FirstElementType = typeof x extends [infer U, ...any[]] ? U : never;
  ```
- got `never`:

  ```js
  type FirstElementType3 = typeof x extends [infer U, ...infer _] ? U : never;
  ```

I use TS v5.2.0. Here you can find a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA2gcgJ5oDQwEy5QBOArgKYC6A3DAPS0wCGEMokUVAsAFA9QYAHMjABiASyLQAogBsyAWzJgoAFUFkAjEhj8hIAGbwYZOFCUATFkTKNz4GRlRiw+skRgBVXADpfjMBgoFBQwAPyeMABcMGBkAG5uNPTGcELAZuYw0ETOAOa4uSCwsQlEfOqiEtJyispqQnjaumQG8CgADNR0DCZpGVnEeQVFMAAU2XkwAD4xJPIARm7TMPMgIHL+AJTlQpWSULIKSqrqAMxN6q0IJmZgljDWtvaOKM6u7l4wvt5vSwD6IXCHiiMXiiW6KT6ZEyEzA+RghWKYLKvFRbGgOjI0Gi4n2h1qJyEWmQaH8jlhuTQNCAA).

I don't want to use `const x = ['y', 2, true] as const;` since I'll get  `'y'` instead of generic `string` type.

Comment: Does [this work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA2gcgJ5oDQwEy5QBOArgKYC6MAhhDKJFANwCwAUO1BgA5kwBiASyLQAogBsyAWzJgoAFR5kAjEhhdeIAGbwYZOFFkATOkTLUj4cRlSCwWskRgBVXADoP1MBhQUqAfhcYAC4YMDIAN0cmGAB6WL04XmBDIxhoIjsAc1wskFhwqKJOJQFhMUkZOUVePDUNMm14FAAGChj4xOTU9OJs3PyYAAoM7JgAHzCSKQAjRwmYGZAQSS8AShLeMpEoCWlZBSUAZnqlJoR9QzATGDMLKxsUOwcnVxgPN2f5gH0AoNDCtE4gl9N0yGlRmAcjA8gVIo52IiOMj2AxoDAtOVdpUDqEhDs9lVDrxVMhMGgYkA)? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: You're starting from `(string | number | boolean)[]`, you've already lost information: https://tsplay.dev/WJpeZN

Comment: I don't want to use `as const` since I cannot do [sth like](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHjAvDA2gcgJ5oDQwEy5QBOArgKYC6A3ALABQ9UGADmTAGICWR0AogDZkAtmTBQAKizIBGJDCasQAM3gwycKKIAmEVJzBKyRGAFVcAOksBDMBhQUKMAPymYALhhgyANyNUYAPQBanCswJpaMNBE+gDmuLEgsF6+RIxSHNx8giJikqx4cgpkyvAoAAzUgcHqYRFRxHEJSTAAFNFxMAA+niRCAEZG3TD9ICCCNgCU6ayZPFACwqISUgDMRVKlCOqaYDp6BkNmMJbm+obGAPqOLibunj5+1SF1ZJEdYPEwicmPaQwA+hAuigSCwJRZBY5ZYeLjzRa5FasWTINCaaBofxAA) `firstElement = 'any string, only y'`

Comment: If you can't use a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), you can't get the type of a particular index.

Comment: but const assertion is the only thing that can make this work, without a function. And the random value thing can be solved like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjaA2W)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
const x = ['y', 2, true];
```

is inferred as:

```
(string | number | boolean)[]
```

And this:

```
const x = ['y', 2, true] as const;
```

Is inferred as:

```
readonly ['y', 2, true]
```

If you want something different, then just make your own type.

```
type MyTuple = [string, number, boolean]
const x: MyTyuple = ['y', 2, true]
type FirstElementType = MyTuple[0];
const test: FirstElementType1 = 'any string'; // fine
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAqBXMAbaBeKBtAzsATgJYB2A5gDRTGIC2ARhPpXQPYtoCGxAugLABQAgMYtieKAA8AXLATI0UTFgDkIZZQBMlAogjcA3AIGhIUAGKF8eAKJoaEYsHjgIARkVQTEFgDNJWAAYDI0F+ETFgTwg8GQsrYFsIe0dnSHdMZS4QKDwiMmV9KCA)

Comment: They asked for how to do this with an array, not a tuple